# Yellow border on hover using ZeroClipboard

Tags: javascript, css, flash, zeroclipboard

I have the following code generating a ZeroClipboard element for me:

```
RunClipboardClient: function (elementSelector) {
    var client = new ZeroClipboard($(elementSelector));

    client.on("load", function (client) {
        client.on("datarequested", function (client) {
            client.setText("Text here");
        });

        client.on("complete", function (client, args) {
            $("#ActiveMenu").hide();
        });
    });
}
```

Im using this in combination with [jQuery Context Menus](http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/) open event. The problem is that there is a odd yellow border around the element when hovering the second time I open the context menu.

[image]

I tried applying `outline: none` to the styling but it did not remove the border. This is the code i'm running when generating the context menu:

```
$(".MenuSmall").destroyContextMenu();

$(".MenuSmall").contextMenu(
    { menu: 'ActiveMenu' },
    // On item clicked
    function (action, element) {
        // Run Menu Item action
    },
    // On close
    function () {
        // Run other code
    },
    // On open
    function (event) {
        self.RunClipboardClient("#pdf_link");
    }
);
```

This is the HTML using for the context menu

```
<ul id="ActiveMenu">
    <li class="MenuPDFLink CustomMenuOption" id="pdf_link"><div class="iconsBlack PDFLink"></div> <a href="#">Link til PDF</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just after creating this question I tried using `ZeroClipboard.destroy();` on the `client complete` event which solved the problem!